# col-padding - How to adjust gutter in Bootstrap 3 grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I reduce the precise gap between the columns so the width of all col remain same and keeping them even with the rest of the page.

```css
.blackbox {
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
}
.content {
        background: #4679BD;
}
.pad-5 [class*="-3"] {
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="blackbox">Hey. I'Black Box</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pad-5">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:

- I tried couple of solutions from different answers asked here on SO but no luck or may be I'm missing something obvious.
- `<div class="col-xs-3"></div>` is inside for each loop.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxqa6wzv/)

Comment: You can customize the settings according to your need from the `Customize and Download` section of bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you reduce the padding of col from `15px` to `5px` the `<div class="row">` which has margin left and right `15px` causing the col uneven, simple solution of this is adjust the margin left and right of `<div class="row">` change its value from `15px` to `-5px` and it will push back the cols inside and make them even and col's width will remain same and it doesn't effect the responsiveness. just add following css to your style sheet

```
.pad-5 {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

```css
.blackbox {
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
}
.content {
        background: #4679BD;
}
.pad-5 {
    margin-left: -5px !important;
    margin-right: -5px !important;
}
.pad-5 [class*="-3"] {
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="blackbox">Hey. I'Black Box</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pad-5">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add in the CSS file the folowing code:

```
.content{
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

or another solution you can add new class:
For Example:

```
<div class="content removespace">
<p>text here</p>
</div>
```

and new css class:

```
.removespace{
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Last_Fl00r/xqmfqe1h/

Comment: you misunderstood the question, i need cols push back inside as they are uneven after reducing the padding from 15px to 5px